# mysql syntax error for the code?

Tags: mysql, database

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user_details ('fname','lname','cname','tno','uname','pwd') VALUES (" +                    fname + "," + lname +"," + cname +","+ tno + "," + uname + "," + pwd +")";

PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) about how to use PreparedStatement parameters so you can avoid SQL injection problems.

Comment: Exactly where does the error occur?

Answer (score 1):

As per your asking You have to put **'** in your provided value as well like you did for you column names.

```
INSERT INTO user_details ('fname','lname','cname','tno','uname','pwd') VALUES ('" + fname + "','" + lname +"','" + cname +"','"+ tno + "','" + uname + "','" + pwd +"')";
```

And if you are using PHP then you probably need **$** before your variables.

remember if **tno** column is a type int then you can quote value with **'** but better to avoid.

**Note**: it is open to SQL Injection so i would suggest you to move to PDO or MySQLi. For security and performance.

**In php** you can write this code for PDO prepared statement

```
$pdoCon = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', 'abc');
$stmt = $pdoCon->prepare("INSERT INTO user_details('fname','lname','cname','tno','uname','pwd') VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $cname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $tno, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->bindParam(5, $uname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->bindParam(6, $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt->execute();
```

Where 20 is the lenght of string (varchar).

**In Java**, Well i saw your edit that you need to do prepared statement in java then here is the correct code

```
try
    {
      CreateConnection();
      CallableStatement calstat = conn.prepareCall("INSERT INTO user_details('fname','lname','cname','tno','uname','pwd') VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
      calstat.setString(1,fname);
      calstat.setString(2,lname);
      calstat.setString(3,cname);
      calstat.setString(4,tno);
      calstat.setString(5,uname);
      calstat.setString(6,pwd);
      calstat.executeUpdate();
      conn.close();
      calstat.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: The field names should not be quoted with single quotes, but optionally with backticks. Also, PDO and MySQLi are for PHP, not Java :)

Comment: Well the user didnt tag for Java particularly and you can see mysql documents for single qoutes. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html example

Answer (score 1):

Don't concat sql string (which is mostly a **SQL Injection**.).

Since you are using preparedStatement, use it like:

```
// column names don't need to be quoted.
sql = "INSERT INTO user_details(fname, lname, cname, tno, uname, pwd) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
// then bind your params
stmt.bindParam(...
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to quote your values with single quotes `'`, and your field names should - if quoted at all - for MySQL be quoted with backticks, not single quotes.

Even better, when using `PreparedStatement` anyway, you'll want to use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injections (for example, if your last name is `O'Connor` just adding quotes in the string will break the SQL). It will also usually improve performance of your queries since the database can easily reuse query plans.

To do this with PreparedStatement (and guessing a little at your types), the code would be something like this;

```java
// Field names are optinally quoted using ` backticks for MySQL
sql = "INSERT INTO user_details (`fname`,`lname`,`cname`,`tno`,`uname`,`pwd`) " +
      "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

// Set all parameters
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, fname);
stmt.setString(2, lname);
stmt.setString(3, cname);
stmt.setInt(4, tno);
stmt.setString(5, uname);
stmt.setString(6, pwd);

// executeUpdate also does inserts, not just updates
stmt.executeUpdate();
```